# Toggle collapse with multiple buttons and div

Tags: jquery, html, class, button

really simply I need the buttons in this code to toggle closed any of the other data-target divs which might be open when the button is clicked.

I tried messing around with accordion functions and so forth, the code looked fine didn't work. I'm super new at this and have spent most of the day chopping away to the point where I've gone cross-eyed through trial and error.

So, if you run the code you'll see a number of buttons. When I click on those buttons I want ONLY the data they call to appear above them. Bonus if you know what to call to highlight the button which is clicked and leave it highlighted while that data is vislble. I'll settle for proper toggling.

This seems like a pretty basic problem and I've searched around a lot, but I couldn't find anything that wasn't either far above my ability level or really relevant. I kept searching 'toggle data-target multiple buttons' and combinations like that. Let me know if you have a fix.

Thanks!
//cheers

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="intro" class="intro">
    <div class="text-content">
      {{ page.basic.content }}
    </div>
   
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
      <p><a class="button" href="/ally">Become an Ally</a></p>
  </div>
     </div>
  
  <div id="demo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
<p>-copy of the annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
        <p><a class="button" href="/advocate">Become an Advocate</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
     
  <div id="demo2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
<p>-copy of annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
      <p>-t shirt</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
         <p><a class="button" href="/defender">Become a Defender</a></p>
    </div>

  <div id="demo3" class="panel-collapse collapse">

 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
<p>-copy of annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
      <p>-t shirt</p>
      <p>-cofee mug or tote bag</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
       <p><a class="button" href="/guardian">Become a Guardian</a></p>
    </div>
  
  <div id="demo4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
<p>-copy of annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
      <p>-t shirt</p>
      <p>-cofee mug or tote bag</p>
      <p>-personal liason at CJFE</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
      <p><a class="button" href="/campaigner">Become a Campaigner</a></p>
    </div>
  
  <div id="demo5" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
 <p>-copy of annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
      <p>-t shirt</p>
      <p>-cofee mug or tote bag</p>
      <p>-personal liason at CJFE</p>
      <p>-VIP invitation to annual gala</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
      <p><a class="button" href="/champion">Become a Champion</a></p>
    </div>
       
   <button type="button"  class="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo5" data-target="#demo5" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$99.99/month - CHAMPION</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo4" data-target="#demo4" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$59.99/month - CAMPAIGNER</h3></button>
   <button type="button"  class="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo3" data-target="#demo3" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$29.99/month - GUARDIAN</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo2" data-target="#demo2" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$14.99/month - DEFENDER - <font color="red">BEST VALUE</font> </h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo1" data-target="#demo1" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$9.99/month - ADVOCATE</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo" data-target="#demo" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$5.00/year - ALLY</h3></button>

</body>
```

Comment: I tried another bit of code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400604/bootstrap-collapse-with-multiple-button-and-div?rq=1

which works fine on that page but won't work properly on mine (doesn't collapse divs or replace the contents, just shows them both and stacks them) even without any edits. Wondering if it's something to do with the libraries or the existing CSS on my website overriding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you would want to change your code to make it easier, but if you want to make it working your way, you need to hide all divs and THEN open yours.

Simply add this to your header:

```js
function hideall() {
    $('.panel-collapse').each(function() {                
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    });
}
```

And put an onclick lister on all divs:

```html
  <button type="button"  class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo5" data-target="#demo5" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$99.99/month - CHAMPION</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo4" data-target="#demo4" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$59.99/month - CAMPAIGNER</h3></button>
   <button type="button"  class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo3" data-target="#demo3" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$29.99/month - GUARDIAN</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo2" data-target="#demo2" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$14.99/month - DEFENDER - <font color="red">BEST VALUE</font> </h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo1" data-target="#demo1" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$9.99/month - ADVOCATE</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo" data-target="#demo" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$5.00/year - ALLY</h3></button>
```

That should do the trick.

See here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function hideall() {
  $('.panel-collapse').each(function() {
            $(this).collapse('hide');
  });
 }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="intro" class="intro">
    <div class="text-content">
      {{ page.basic.content }}
    </div>
   
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
      <p><a class="button" href="/ally">Become an Ally</a></p>
  </div>
     </div>
  
  <div id="demo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
<p>-copy of the annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
        <p><a class="button" href="/advocate">Become an Advocate</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
     
  <div id="demo2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
<p>-copy of annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
      <p>-t shirt</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
         <p><a class="button" href="/defender">Become a Defender</a></p>
    </div>

  <div id="demo3" class="panel-collapse collapse">

 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
<p>-copy of annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
      <p>-t shirt</p>
      <p>-cofee mug or tote bag</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
       <p><a class="button" href="/guardian">Become a Guardian</a></p>
    </div>
  
  <div id="demo4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
<p>-copy of annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
      <p>-t shirt</p>
      <p>-cofee mug or tote bag</p>
      <p>-personal liason at CJFE</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
      <p><a class="button" href="/campaigner">Become a Campaigner</a></p>
    </div>
  
  <div id="demo5" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <td style="text-align:left">
        <div>
<p>-invitation to AGM</p>
<p>-invitations to ally-only events</p>
<p>-monthly electronic newsletter</p>
 <p>-copy of annual review</p>
      <p>-sticker pack</p>
      <p>-t shirt</p>
      <p>-cofee mug or tote bag</p>
      <p>-personal liason at CJFE</p>
      <p>-VIP invitation to annual gala</p>
           </div>
          </td>
      <th>
        <img src ="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8246/8560552146_6b50021122.jpg" align = "right" height="200" width="200" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 40px">
      </th>
    </tr>
      </table>
      <p><a class="button" href="/champion">Become a Champion</a></p>
    </div>
       
   <button type="button"  class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo5" data-target="#demo5" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$99.99/month - CHAMPION</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo4" data-target="#demo4" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$59.99/month - CAMPAIGNER</h3></button>
   <button type="button"  class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo3" data-target="#demo3" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$29.99/month - GUARDIAN</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo2" data-target="#demo2" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$14.99/month - DEFENDER - <font color="red">BEST VALUE</font> </h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo1" data-target="#demo1" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$9.99/month - ADVOCATE</h3></button>
   <button type="button" class="button" onclick="hideall()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo" data-target="#demo" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;"> <h3 style= "font-family:US101; color:#FFF;">$5.00/year - ALLY</h3></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Regards

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. Didn't think of onclick, but that makes perfect sense. You rock!