# Expand and Collapse with multiple buttons and divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help in collapsing the divs when the button is clicked again.

I have this code:

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('.collapse').hide();
  $('#demo').show();
});
$('#btn2').click(function() {
  $('.collapse').hide();
  $('#demo1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#demo" id="btn1">Company Details</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#demo1" id="btn2">Commercial Details</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    1st div
  </div>
  <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    2nd div
  </div>
</div>
```

From here: [Bootstrap Collapse with multiple button and div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400604/bootstrap-collapse-with-multiple-button-and-div)

This code works and hides div1 when the button2 is clicked and expands div2 but it does not hide the div2 when button2 is clicked again.

Is there a way to show div1 when button1 is clicked and hide the div1 when button2 is clicked and expand div2. But when button2 is clicked again, it hides div2 and hence all the collapsible divs are collapsed and this behaviour works with button1 and div1 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your script like this

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){

      if($('#demo').is(':visible')){
           $('#demo').hide();
      }else{
          $('#demo1').hide();
          $('#demo').show();

      }

    });
    $('#btn2').click(function(){

      if($('#demo1').is(':visible')){
           $('#demo1').hide();
      }else{
           $('#demo').hide();
          $('#demo1').show();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Initially both div are open and if you click on button 1 it hide div1 not div 2

Comment: @Bhuwan I edited the code a little and got the results that I wanted following the method given by Ajeesh KH

Comment: @HamzaAhmad Agreed...:) but you also have to mention to the answerer that he need to edit his answer so that it will help to the other user also

Comment: @Bhuwan Thanks :) Will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#btn1').click(function(){
 // $('.collapse').hide();
  $('#demo1').hide();
  $('#demo').show();
});
$('#btn2').click(function(){
  //$('.collapse').hide();
  $('#demo').hide();
  $('#demo1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-
    target="#demo" id="btn1" >Company Details</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-
    target="#demo1" id="btn2">Commercial Details</button>
      <div id="demo" class="collapse" >
        1st div
      </div>

      <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
        2nd div
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to hide both the div at first and then you can use `toggle`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('#demo1,#demo').hide()
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#demo1').hide();
  $('#demo').toggle();
});
$('#btn2').click(function() {
  $('#demo').hide();
  $('#demo1').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#demo" id="btn1">Company Details</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#demo1" id="btn2">Commercial Details</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    1st div
  </div>
  <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    2nd div
  </div>
</div>
```